# Match paren problem in the GUI version of Emacs

Tags: package, gui-emacs

I use the built in parentheses match `(show-paren-mode t)`.
But there seems to be somewhat of a glitch when it highlights the matching parentheses, because it moves the bottom lines further apart when the highlights appear.

Like this:

[image]

Is this a bug or an intended effect? If the former, how would I go about fixing it?

* Solution in comments

Comment: I can't reproduce that on Emacs 24.1.50 with emacs -Q. I suspect it has something to do with the particular font/face settings you're using.

Comment: I don't see this either, with Emacs 25.1.1. Have you customized the `show-paren-match` face by any chance?

Comment: Ok, I found the culprit. `(when window-system(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 160 50))` This was meant to start the window at a specified size. Is there anything wrong with this setting? I think I copied it from the emacs wiki.

Comment: Looks like there some underline or overlain settings of the match faces.